# PostgreSQL Full Text Search - Ranking search results based on their position in the search value

Tags: database, postgresql, full-text-search

Considering keywords like `tablet` and `phone` are to be searched for within a specific sentence like `Looking for tablets and phones`.

Even though when we do

```sql
select to_tsvector('english', 'Looking for tablets and phones')
```

it returns the lexemes along with their positions

```
'look':1 'phone':5 'tablet':3
```

When I try to rank them, it gives the same rank value for both keywords.

```sql
select keyword, ts_rank(tsv, tsq, 1) as rank
from 
    to_tsvector('english', 'Looking for tablets and phones') tsv,
    (values
        ('phone' , to_tsquery('english', 'phone')),
        ('tablet', to_tsquery('english', 'tablet'))
    ) as d (keyword, tsq)
order by rank desc
```

Output:

```
 keyword |    rank
---------+-------------
 phone   | 0.030396355
 tablet  | 0.030396355
```

How can I rank the keywords according to their occurrence position?

Comment: I can't reproduce the equal rank, since 'tablets' and 'tables' are different things.  Is that a typo in your question?

Comment: @jjanes - Yes, it's a typo. Sorry for that! I fixed it. Hope you've got a way in your mind to help me out with this!